# React Native Picker with Image Icon

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build a language selection picker in react native which has a picture of the country's flag next to the label, like this:

[image]

The icons have to be images and not unicode. I've had a look around but there doesn't seem to be anything available. Does anyone know of anything I can use to create this?

If nothing can be used then I will create a custom picker, I aim to make use of a ScrollView to handle the scrolling but I am not sure what I can use to replicate the rotation effect of the native iOS picker, so if anyone can help me with this also I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You can try this package https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown.

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi This library does not appear to have this functionality? It needs to rotate like in the image I posted.

Comment: Try creating a simple Modal and inside modal use a Flatlist. For the flatlist data send component with image and text. I hope you can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-country-picker-modal

It's not inside a native picker like your screenshot, but it should do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emoji by copy from online emoji website(many available on internet) and add picker item code as below,

```
<Picker.Item label="  France" value="fr" />
```